# Xamarin ExifInterface.SaveAttributes Overwrites image with no image data

Tags: android, xamarin, exif

I am opening a previously saved image and writing a few attributes based on data that comes in a bit later in the process. When I save the attributes the image is overwritten(which I would expect). However, all the image data is missing and it is only header information. Am I missing something?

```
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(m_LastPictureName);
            exif.SetAttribute(ExifInterface.TagArtist, "xxxx");
            exif.SaveAttributes();  // Currently this is dropping ALL image data but saving only EXIF information - why???
```

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: did you read the note here?  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface#saveAttributes()

Comment: I appreciate the response, but there are no get*** calls after. As soon as SaveAttributes() is called I see the file size go from ~15KB to 35 bytes.

Comment: not that, this: "This is expensive because it involves copying all the data from one file to another and deleting the old file and renaming the other. It's best to use setAttribute"

Comment: Oh. Yes, I seen this which is why I expected the image to be 'overwritten'. I can see if change in size, but the name remains the same. My question is where is all the other data going? Am I doing something wrong in terms of not preserving something manually? To me it seems that SaveAttributes() should handle everything needed.

Comment: I do have additional output enabled now and I am seeing this:                                ExifInterface(20159): Skip the tag entry since tag number is not defined: 2
ExifInterface(20159): Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0

Comment: OK, I misread that - it is suggesting you call Save a single time after setting all attributes - which is what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My fix was to install the Android.Support.Media.ExifInterface in place of Android.Media.ExifInterface.

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).