# xamarin forms Android How to add Metadata to an image being copied to a Public Directory

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, exif

In our Xamarin Forms app, I have to

1. take a picture and save it locally.
2. add a variety of metadata to it.
3. make a copy of the picture, complete with all metadata, available on a globally accessible location so that it can be easily added to an email or shared some other way.

1. is easy and can be accomplished for Android, iOS and UWP using
   Xamarin Forms.
2. can be done on each platform using a DependencyService. For **Android** I access the EXIF values of an image by using:

   ExifInterface newExif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

Then I set all the EXIF values that I need to and save them back to the image.

3. Using another DependencyService I can write out a copy of the image to, say, Pictures.

**What I can't figure out is how to access the resulting image to add the EXIF data.**

This is what I've got:

```
public void SaveFileToPublicDirectory(string internalPath, string name)
{
    string path = "";
    try 
    {                
        // decode a bitmap from a local file path.
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(internalPath);
        System.IO.Stream fos;

        // today I am concentrating on BuildVersionCodes.Q and later
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Q)
        {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.Put(MediaStore.IMediaColumns.DisplayName, name);
            contentValues.Put(MediaStore.IMediaColumns.MimeType, "image/jpg");
            contentValues.Put(MediaStore.IMediaColumns.RelativePath,
                Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures);

            var imageUri = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.
                Insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, contentValues);
            fos = Android.App.Application.Context.ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(imageUri);
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fos);

            path = imageUri.ToString(); // + "/" + name;
            Log.Debug("i-Trax Droid", "Path for saving file in Pictures = " + path);
            // path looks something like : content:/media/external/images/media/594
        }
        else
        {
            String imagesDir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).ToString();
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(imagesDir, name);
            fos = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fos);
            Util.PathFilenameForPicturesDir_Android = path;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = string.Format("** Exception in SaveFileToPublicDirectory: {0} ", ex.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        Util.WriteExceptionToSQL(msg);
    }

    return;
}
```

What I am expecting to be able to do is get the ExifInterface from the recently written out file, **but how do I read in EXIF data from**

```
content:/media/external/images/media/594
```

And then I am hoping to be able make the required changes to the EXIF and save it back.

Comment: Does [ExifInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.media.exifinterface?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12) have what you need? (If so, and you get it working, please add Your Answer below, to help others.) See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/64126523/199364

Comment: if you 2) add EXIF data, then 3) copy the image (with EXIF) to Pictures, then where is the problem?  Why do you need to open the file again to add the EXIF data?  EXIF data is embedded in the file and should be copied to the new file

Comment: @Jason I agree, it should work. But in practice, I find that the Metadata gets dropped/lost during the copy.

Comment: Generally speaking,you can get/set Exif data by this API [Android.Media.ExifInterface Api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface) .

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT (ran out of time for an edit :- (   What is puzzling me is that when I write the image to DirectoryPictures, I get some path that looks like: content:/media/external/images/media/594 when I am expecting something with a path + fileName + fileType that I can then get it's EXIF data so I can make the required changes to it and write it back. That is how I did it for the image in the app's sandbox. But for doing it in DirectoryPictures I am stuck.